# Best Way to Combine 9 sided NGon in Scooter Model

Tags: mesh

I need to fix the topology on the seat piece of the scooter here so that there isn't any pinching, but still maintains a somewhat square shape. How would you go about fixing the massive 10 sided (I think) NGon in the screenshot?

[The Blend File](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50687)

[image]

Comment: why don't you simply do something like this: https://zupimages.net/up/18/45/hcu8.jpg

Comment: also you could separate the meshes, especially when they are completely different objects

Comment: @moonboots not necessary. That's more work than needs to be done.

Comment: actually sometimes it much more easy, for example here I don't see why keeping only one mesh, even if it's a nice challenge

Comment: Solid objects like this don't need to be separated, though. When I made low-poly chess pieces, I didn't bother with having separate meshes. I think it depends on what the final goal is, too. And for exporting (I'm presuming that's what he'll end up doing), it's not going to work if he doesn't join all meshes together.

Comment: maybe in some cases you must not separate some meshes, I don't know